# The correct way to draw text in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, iphone, c++, opengl-es-2.0, bitmap-fonts

I am using PowerVR OpenGL ES 2 SDK to develop my game on Windows with C++ then I can port it to android or iphone.

Everything look alright but I'm now stuck with text rendering. I can't found any detailed tutorial about rendering text (using TTF or Bitmap font) in OpenGL ES 2.0 by using C++.
I found many topic talk about rendering text on android or iphone by using java or objective-c (with a textview, surfaceview or some blah blah things) but I don't think that's what I need. I need a "cross-platform solution". (or may be I am wrong at this point?)

After a little research, I have the solution in my mind:

**Load and bind bitmap font texture** -> **Parse text and generate and bind vertices array, mapping texture with uv array,...** -> **Render it to screen**

I'm not tested yet but I think it's a problem when using my solution: When I want to change text (for example: I am making a user score, or a timer on screen) I must re-bind the vertices array and uv array, it's not a good idea, right?

Is there any better way/right way to draw bitmap font on screen with OpenGL ES 2?

Answer (score 4):

The solution that you mention is the way to go, and indeed, if you modify your text, you'll have to recreate the geometry that represents it, and resubmit it to OpenGL.

This recreation step will take some time, but surely not excessively much.

For rendering text, the problem has two main components :

- create your texture atlas bitmap
- draw the text using this texture, considering the font metrics (size, kerning, etc.) and possibly subpixel antialiasing

To create your texture atlas, you can find some code around (probably using freetype) or use an existing tool (such as [AngleCode's bmfont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/)).

For drawing, you'll probably want to roll out your own code, based on some existing code, as there are lot of details to get right for good looking text. To start your headache, you can have a look at [this article](http://www.antigrain.com/research/font_rasterization/).

One good modern source of inspiration could be [Nicolas Rougier's freetype-gl](http://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/) code.

Comment: Does anyone have a OpenGL ES 2.0 Android example that supports rotation?

Answer (score 2):

text rendering is one of the topic most new comers need to face sooner or later in the 3D libraries world.

There are a lot of tutorials around the internet about text rendering, many books talking about it. My advice is to look around and try to understand how they work.

TTF fonts are not a viable solution since, in a real time computing scenario (like a computer game), the geometry based technique of TTF is way too much resource consuming.

A very common solution (the one I use in my PATRIA 3D engine for example) is to use a texture atlas containing the glyph of the different characters, then your application logic needs to handle the text-->glyph position relation for the texturing of quads that will compose your final "on screen text".

Text rendering is not a simple topic since it involves topics as kerning/spacing/different text sized etc.

Try to follow this link to best understand the topic (if I am not wrong, the author of this wiki is an active member of this very community).

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_01

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to draw text in a game is to use texture atlases with glyphs containing distance fields:  https://www.mapbox.com/blog/text-signed-distance-fields/

Also see this Siggraph paper from Valve (the creators of Half-Life and Portal) describing variations of the technique: http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf

The distance field-based text quality is much higher than plain bitmap based text. It also uses less memory because distance field is smaller than verbatim bitmap representation of font.